# JOPtionPane Character Count In a Text File

Tags: java, eclipse

I need to know what my program is doing. I've used other answers to other questions to patch together this Frankenstein of a program.

Another thing is the code should gather the character count in a text file and it is one letter off so i don't know what to do. If you could tell me what my if statement is doing that'd be greatly appreciated,

```
import java.io.*;

import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    public class File_Letter_Counter{

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{      

        //Declare variables.
        //Hold fileName variable.
        String fileName;
        //Set accumulator value.
        int accumulator=0;
        //Set fileName equal to user input.
        fileName=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the name of a file: ");
        //Set letter for file search.
        String letter=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a letter: ");
        //Set char variable to string input's letter.
        char character=(Character.toLowerCase(letter.charAt(0)));

        //Open file.
        File file=new File (fileName);
        //Set new scanner object to read file.
        Scanner inputFile=new Scanner(file);
        //Loop for every line in file.  
        while (inputFile.hasNext()){
        //Set line equal to the next line that is in the file.
        String line=inputFile.nextLine();
        /*For every time count is less than the number 
        of characters in the string, repeat the loop.*/
        for(int count=0; count<line.length(); count++){
        /*if line 1 is equal to lower case "character" variable

         */
        if (line.charAt(count)==Character.toLowerCase(character)
        ||line.charAt(count)==Character.toUpperCase(character)){

        count++;

        accumulator++;

                }
            }
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, accumulator);
        inputFile.close();
    }   
}
```

Comment: This is **your** code. **YOU** should know what it's doing.

Comment: Run it step-by-step under debugger and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you could tell me what my if statement is doing that'd be greatly
>   appreciated.

```
 if (line.charAt(count)==Character.toLowerCase(character) ||line.charAt(count)==Character.toUpperCase(character))
```

This if statement above basically takes the character at the specified index within the string and checks whether it's equal to the character to the right. Also within that process, the Character being compared to is being changed to lowercase and uppercase respectively for equality as the character could either be Uppercase or Lowercase. Eventually, this if statement will either validate to true if one of the expressions is true or false if both validate to false.

Comment: Thank you @Ousmane Diaw I appreciate it! As I said the program was a compilation of things that worked individually and put together I was baffled.

Comment: Oh, I see. well anyway if the solution has solved your question I would really appreciate it if you vote the answer as accepted. Also, can you please read the documentation as that will give you more information regarding how to post good questions. Thank you!

Comment: @OusameDiaw I believe I tagged you right this time!

Comment: @OusameDiaw I will do!